# Can APFS containers be resized while retaining their contents? (Case-sensitive, encrypted)

Tags: macos, time-machine, disk-utility, partition, apfs

Can APFS (Case-sensitive, encrypted) containers be resized while retaining their contents (e.g. not having to reformat them) in MacOS?

I have an external hard drive with 3 different Time Machine backup destinations corresponding to 3 different Macs, and these backups reside respectively in 3 different APFS (Case-sensitive, encrypted) container volumes on the drive.

2 of these containers have too little storage allocated for their growing backups, while 1 of the containers has too much storage allocated. Can I resize the containers e.g. in Disk Utility > Partition without losing my Time Machine data?

---

NB: It occurred to me that my setup of using 3 different containers may not be the most optimal solution, and that instead 1 container with 3 volumes might be better. Related question: [Time Machine backups of Multiple Macs to external drive with APFS: Should I use separate containers, or one container with different volumes?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/457903/time-machine-backups-of-multiple-macs-to-external-drive-with-apfs-should-i-use)